# How to create a json object out of structs

Tags: go

I'm very new to golang and I'd like to make a json object like this:

```
{
    "name" : "animals",
    "children" : [
        {"name":"dog", "value": 5},
        {"name":"cat", "value": 4},
        {"name":"fish", "value": 10}
    ]
}
```

The code that I came up with:

```
type Child struct {
        Name string
        Value int
    }

type DataMap struct {
        Name string
        Children []Child
    }    
m := DataMap{"animals", [{"cat": 5 }, {"dog": 4}, {"fish":10}] }  
cj, _ := json.Marshal(m)
```

But I get error:

```
   syntax error: unexpected {, expecting expression
```

Ideally, I'd like to append the `Children` slice to the `DataMap` in a loop but I don't know how to do so. 
Appreciate your hints.

Comment: In the line you assign `m`, replace all `:` to `,`. It is trivial syntax error.

Comment: Still get the same error: https://play.golang.org/p/OwqJ1RVmkjl

Comment: and more trivial syntax errors. Field Value shall be of `int` and `[...]` `[]Child{...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstand the struct initialization syntax(as many new incomers), here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Child struct {
        Name string
        Value int
    }

type DataMap struct {
        Name string
        Children []Child
    }    

func main() {
    m := DataMap{"animals", []Child{{"cat", 5}, {"dog", 10 } } }  
    cj, _ := json.Marshal(m)

    fmt.Printf("%s", cj)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/qkcAzPg6sQq

In a loop:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Child struct {
        Name string
        Value int
    }

type DataMap struct {
        Name string
        Children []Child
    }    

func main() {
    m := DataMap{"animals", []Child{}}
    for _, item := range []Child{{"cat", 5}, {"dog", 10 }} {
       m.Children = append(m.Children, item)
    }
    cj, _ := json.Marshal(m)

    fmt.Printf("%s", cj)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/yZGgD9jcPGu

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2):

```
type DataMap struct {
        Name string
        Children []map[string]int
}
```

no need to change `:` to `,` too

also notice that the error is compile time error not runtime

[here](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) is a tool I use when my json is too big and i want struct out of it

Comment: Sorry, I need the values to be `int`. Please see the updated question.

Comment: take anothe look

Answer (score 0):

To put the quotation for all field
The below code

```
{"name":"dog", "value": 5},
{"name":"cat", "value": 4},
{"name":"fish", "value": 10}
```

as follows

```
{"name":"dog", "value": "5"},
{"name":"cat", "value": "4"},
{"name":"fish", "value": "10"}
```

I hope this is help for u